# Arduino Nano BLE 33 with DFPlayer not working

Tags: arduino, arduino-nano, software-serial

I'm pretty new with Arduino circuits and I'm trying to connect a DFPlayer Mini to Arduino Nano BLE 33 Sense. If I understood correctly the library "SoftwareSerial" doesn't work on the BLE Sense and I'm not able to find a way to make the DFPlayer work properly (I also tried to use HardwareSerial but for some reason it doesn't work). Do you know any way I can fix the connection or find a replacement library?
Here is my code

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h"




//mp3

SoftwareSerial mySoftwareSerial(12, 11); // RX, TX (meno 11)
DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer;
void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value);





void setup(void) {
  

  //mp3
   
    
    if (!myDFPlayer.begin(mySoftwareSerial)) {  //Use softwareSerial to communicate with mp3.
    Serial.println(F("Unable to begin:"));
    Serial.println(F("1.Please recheck the connection!"));
    Serial.println(F("2.Please insert the SD card!"));
    while(true);
  }
   myDFPlayer.setTimeOut(500); //Set serial communictaion time out 500ms

  //----Set volume----
  myDFPlayer.volume(3);//et volume value (0~30).
  myDFPlayer.volumeUp(); //Volume Up
  myDFPlayer.volumeDown(); //Volume Down
  
  //----Set device we use SD as default----
  myDFPlayer.outputDevice(DFPLAYER_DEVICE_SD);
  
  //----Set different EQ----
  myDFPlayer.EQ(DFPLAYER_EQ_NORMAL);


   //mp3
    static unsigned long timer = millis();

  if (millis() - timer > 3000) {
    timer = millis();
    myDFPlayer.next();  //Play next mp3 every 3 second.
  }


  if (myDFPlayer.available()) {
    printDetail(myDFPlayer.readType(), myDFPlayer.read()); //Print the detail message from DFPlayer to handle different errors and states.
  }

  // wait for a short amount of time -- sometimes a short delay of 5ms will help
   // technically we only need to execute this one time, since we aren't changing the colors but we will build on this structure
   //----Mp3 play----
    //Play the first mp3 


}


void loop(void) {

  myDFPlayer.play(1);

}


//Mp3 
void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value){
  switch (type) {
    case TimeOut:
      Serial.println(F("Time Out!"));
      break;
    case WrongStack:
      Serial.println(F("Stack Wrong!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardInserted:
      Serial.println(F("Card Inserted!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardRemoved:
      Serial.println(F("Card Removed!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardOnline:
      Serial.println(F("Card Online!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerPlayFinished:
      Serial.print(F("Number:"));
      Serial.print(value);
      Serial.println(F(" Play Finished!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerError:
      Serial.print(F("DFPlayerError:"));
      switch (value) {
        case Busy:
          Serial.println(F("Card not found"));
          break;
        case Sleeping:
          Serial.println(F("Sleeping"));
          break;
        case SerialWrongStack:
          Serial.println(F("Get Wrong Stack"));
          break;
        case CheckSumNotMatch:
          Serial.println(F("Check Sum Not Match"));
          break;
        case FileIndexOut:
          Serial.println(F("File Index Out of Bound"));
          break;
        case FileMismatch:
          Serial.println(F("Cannot Find File"));
          break;
        case Advertise:
          Serial.println(F("In Advertise"));
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
 }
```

The error I get by compiling is this

```
Arduino: 1.8.16 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Nano 33 BLE"











/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:362:2: error: #error This version of SoftwareSerial supports only 20, 16 and 8MHz processors
 #error This version of SoftwareSerial supports only 20, 16 and 8MHz processors
  ^~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'bool SoftwareSerial::listen()':
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:418:23: error: 'SREG' was not declared in this scope
     uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
                       ^~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:418:23: note: suggested alternative: 'SING'
     uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
                       ^~~~
                       SING
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:419:5: error: 'cli' was not declared in this scope
     cli();
     ^~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'void SoftwareSerial::setTX(uint8_t)':
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:593:22: error: 'digitalPinToBitMask' was not declared in this scope
   _transmitBitMask = digitalPinToBitMask(tx);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:593:22: note: suggested alternative: 'digitalPinToPinName'
   _transmitBitMask = digitalPinToBitMask(tx);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                      digitalPinToPinName
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:595:27: error: 'portOutputRegister' was not declared in this scope
   _transmitPortRegister = portOutputRegister(port);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:595:27: note: suggested alternative: '_transmitPortRegister'
   _transmitPortRegister = portOutputRegister(port);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                           _transmitPortRegister
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'void SoftwareSerial::setRX(uint8_t)':
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:604:21: error: 'digitalPinToBitMask' was not declared in this scope
   _receiveBitMask = digitalPinToBitMask(rx);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:604:21: note: suggested alternative: 'digitalPinToPinName'
   _receiveBitMask = digitalPinToBitMask(rx);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     digitalPinToPinName
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:606:26: error: 'portInputRegister' was not declared in this scope
   _receivePortRegister = portInputRegister(port);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'void SoftwareSerial::begin(long int)':
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:617:31: error: 'table' was not declared in this scope
   for (unsigned i=0; i<sizeof(table)/sizeof(table[0]); ++i)
                               ^~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:617:31: note: suggested alternative: 'tanl'
   for (unsigned i=0; i<sizeof(table)/sizeof(table[0]); ++i)
                               ^~~~~
                               tanl
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:633:9: error: 'digitalPinToPCICR' was not declared in this scope
     if (digitalPinToPCICR(_receivePin))
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:633:9: note: suggested alternative: 'digitalPinToPort'
     if (digitalPinToPCICR(_receivePin))
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         digitalPinToPort
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:635:46: error: 'digitalPinToPCICRbit' was not declared in this scope
       *digitalPinToPCICR(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCICRbit(_receivePin));
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:635:46: note: suggested alternative: 'digitalPinToPort'
       *digitalPinToPCICR(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCICRbit(_receivePin));
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                              digitalPinToPort
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:635:42: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope
       *digitalPinToPCICR(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCICRbit(_receivePin));
                                          ^~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:635:42: note: suggested alternative: '_B'
       *digitalPinToPCICR(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCICRbit(_receivePin));
                                          ^~~
                                          _B
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:636:8: error: 'digitalPinToPCMSK' was not declared in this scope
       *digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:636:8: note: suggested alternative: 'digitalPinToPort'
       *digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        digitalPinToPort
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:636:46: error: 'digitalPinToPCMSKbit' was not declared in this scope
       *digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:636:46: note: suggested alternative: 'digitalPinToPort'
       *digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                              digitalPinToPort
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'void SoftwareSerial::end()':
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:651:7: error: 'digitalPinToPCMSK' was not declared in this scope
   if (digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin))
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:651:7: note: suggested alternative: 'digitalPinToPort'
   if (digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin))
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       digitalPinToPort
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:652:45: error: 'digitalPinToPCMSKbit' was not declared in this scope
     *digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) &= ~_BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:652:45: note: suggested alternative: 'digitalPinToPort'
     *digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) &= ~_BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                             digitalPinToPort
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:652:41: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope
     *digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) &= ~_BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));
                                         ^~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:652:41: note: suggested alternative: '_B'
     *digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) &= ~_BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));
                                         ^~~
                                         _B
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'virtual size_t SoftwareSerial::write(uint8_t)':
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:687:21: error: 'SREG' was not declared in this scope
   uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
                     ^~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:687:21: note: suggested alternative: 'SING'
   uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
                     ^~~~
                     SING
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:688:3: error: 'cli' was not declared in this scope
   cli();  // turn off interrupts for a clean txmit
   ^~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:692:26: error: 'XMIT_START_ADJUSTMENT' was not declared in this scope
   tunedDelay(_tx_delay + XMIT_START_ADJUSTMENT);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'virtual void SoftwareSerial::flush()':
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:735:21: error: 'SREG' was not declared in this scope
   uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
                     ^~~~
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:735:21: note: suggested alternative: 'SING'
   uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
                     ^~~~
                     SING
/Users/matteopaoli/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial-master/SoftwareSerial.cpp:736:3: error: 'cli' was not declared in this scope
   cli();
   ^~~
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Nano 33 BLE.


This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use Serial1 instead of SoftwareSerial. pins RX/TX on the board are Serial1

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175348/softwareserial-for-arduino-nano-33-iot) an example of getting Uart serial for Nano 33 IoT.

Comment: @mmixLinus, Nano BLE is nRF5, not SAMD as Nano IoT. both have Serial1 ready without additional instantiation